# Scope of a function inside an Angular JS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What scope is a function defined inside an angular js controller, part of?

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

    function log() {
        console.log('Vanakkam Ulagam');
    }

    var functionToCall = 'log';

    ????????[functionToCall]();

}])
```

I tried MyCtrl, this and $window. I can access the function by namespacing it like so `functions.print = function()` and then using `functions[functionToCall]()`.

I am more interested in accessing the function without namespacing it. Is it possible? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is solution for this question

```
var f;
var a = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
a.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.log=function(){
         console.log('test');
    }
    f=$scope.log;           
});
```

and this function useable to element html for example

```
    <button ng-click='log()'></button>
or
    <button onclick='f()'></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to access global functions in your controller code, `window` (or `$window` if it's properly injected) should work fine:

`$scope.alert = function(text) { window.alert(text) }`

To be extra sure this works in other environments you could manually bind it in a self-invoking anonymous function:

`(function(global){ //make the global scope assigned to the variable global
      app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
          $scope.alert = global.alert;
       }]);
   )(this); //this is the global object when this is evaluated`

If you want to do anything inside an expression on a DOM element (such as `ng-click`), it's important to realise that angular expressions are evaluated by Angular's own expression evaluator (namely through [$scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)). So if something is not attached to a scope, it cannot be used in an angular expression.

However, if you were to do something like attach the global object to the scope, then everything is fair game. This really isn't recommended (I think there's no real reason to do this, and its better to manually define functions you need), but :

`$scope.global = window`

Inside your controller definition should work. You can then do things like `ng-click="global.alert('Yo SO!')"` in your DOM without issues.

For better testability you could use [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) (you said you tried it and it didn't work... are you sure you injected it properly? Look at the example in the documentation carefully). But like I said, if you're attaching the global object to the scope you're opening Pandora's Box.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I understand how to access global variables, scope variables. What I want to know is what scope does a function defined inside the controller belong to? I want to know what can replace the ?s and make it work.

Comment: Inside a controller it's just javascript. You could just use window for that.

A function defined inside a controller won't belong to an angular scope unless you explicitly add it there